# How to store 0.5 in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store `0.5` in mysql database. How can I do this?

I have a column with `decimal(10,2)` in my mysql database. But when I store `0.5` by using php, it stores `0`.

It is affective when I store `1.1` or above this.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sub'])){ 
    include('conn.php');  

    echo $package_name = $_POST['package_name'];  
    echo $package_amount = $_POST['package_amount'];  
    echo $package_points = $_POST['package_points'];
    echo $package_direct = $_POST['package_direct'];  
    echo $package_binary = $_POST['package_binary'];  

    $package = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO package(pack_name, pack_amount, pack_points, pack_direct, pack_binary) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');  
    $package->bind_param('siiii', $package_name, $package_amount, $package_points, $package_direct, $package_binary);  
    if($package->execute()){  
        echo "Pakage Inserted ";  
    }else{  
        echo "error";  
    }  
     $package->close();  
}  


?>
```

Thank you

Comment: mysql will correctly store 0.5 as 0.50. So my guess is your php code is at fault.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a float instead.

```
CREATE TABLE amounts(
  id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  amount FLOAT(2,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

when you are setting up a float, the numbers in the `()` are the number of places before and after the decimal point. For example, if I wanted a percentage, I would set the type to `FLOAT(3,2)` so that I am able to store the value `100.00`

If you are still having problems, it could be a rounding issue with PHP. You should post your code on your question so we can take a look :)